# Draw a line point by point in android

Tags: java, android, draw, paint

I am new in android native development . I need help from you guys.

**My Question :**

In my main activity there are 9 points and i want to draw line from one point to other point with user touchevent . I have one image i share with you over here.

[Image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x9j3ez5ogxjhjr2/Screenshot%202014-11-04%2018.01.56.png?dl=0)

If any one have any useful sample code please share with me .

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer:
create your own View by extending View class and you will have a canvas in onDraw method of View ,then your can draw whatever you want.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html